# Python How to pivot this table

Tags: python, pandas

Hi there I have a table that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                  'PatientID':[101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102],
                  'RequestDate':['2020-02-10','2020-02-10','2020-02-11','2020-02-11',
                                 '2020-02-12','2020-02-12','2020-02-13','2020-02-13'],
                  'CollectionDate':['2020-02-11','2020-02-11','2020-02-12','2020-02-12',
                                    '2020-02-13','2020-02-13','2020-02-14','2020-02-14'],
                  'TestCode':['ALT','AST','CRE','DB','ALT','AST','CRE','DB'],
                  'TestResult':[21, 27, 94, 2, 25, 22, 98, 3],
                  'Units':['U/L','U/L','umol/L','umol/L','U/L','U/L','umol/L','umol/L']})
```

[image]

In python, how can I pivot it to get the following expected output:

[image]

This is a little tricky as it seems to be panel data, ie time series + cross sectional data.

Comment: Was the data read in from an SQL database?  If it was, you could have done a pivot in SQL and then read in the result in pandas.

Comment: yes it was read in frm SQL DB. how can I pivot this in MsSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
# pivot
new_df = (df.set_index(['CaseNo', 'PatientID','RequestDate','CollectionDate','TestCode'])
   .unstack('TestCode')

)

# fill in the missing `Units`:
new_df['Units'] = (new_df['Units'].groupby(['CaseNo','PatientID']).ffill()
                         .groupby(['CaseNo','PatientID']).bfill()
                  )

# rename columns
new_df.columns = [f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}' if x[0]=='Units' else x[1] for x in new_df.columns]

# sort columns and reset index
new_df = new_df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      CaseNo    PatientID  RequestDate    CollectionDate      ALT  ALT_Units      AST  AST_Units      CRE  CRE_Units      DB  DB_Units
--  --------  -----------  -------------  ----------------  -----  -----------  -----  -----------  -----  -----------  ----  ----------
 0         1          101  2020-02-10     2020-02-11           21  U/L             27  U/L            nan  umol/L        nan  umol/L
 1         1          101  2020-02-11     2020-02-12          nan  U/L            nan  U/L             94  umol/L          2  umol/L
 2         2          102  2020-02-12     2020-02-13           25  U/L             22  U/L            nan  umol/L        nan  umol/L
 3         2          102  2020-02-13     2020-02-14          nan  U/L            nan  U/L             98  umol/L          3  umol/L
```

Comment: thanks I like your solution. Could u explain ````new_df.columns = [f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}' if x[0]=='Units' else x[1] for x in new_df.columns]```` ,especially the ````f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}'```` part?

Comment: That’s called f-string, you can look it up.

Answer (score 2):

```
#pivot data and reset index on Units
res = (df.pivot_table(values=['TestResult'], 
                      index=['CaseNo', 'PatientID', 'RequestDate', 'CollectionDate'],
                      columns=['TestCode','Units'])
       .droplevel(0,axis=1)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(-1)
      )

#sort Units column
arr = res.Units.sort_values().array

#create pairing of Units with rest of column names
from itertools import product
new_cols = ["_".join(ent) for ent in product(res.columns[1:], ['Units'])]

#pair units with new_col and assign to dataframe
mapp = dict(zip(new_cols,arr))
out = res.assign(**mapp).drop('Units', axis = 1).rename_axis(None,axis=1)

out

                                                ALT AST     CRE  DB ALT_Units   AST_Units   CRE_Units   DB_Units
CaseNo  PatientID   RequestDate CollectionDate                              
   1    101       2020-02-10    2020-02-11     21.0 27.0    NaN   NaN   U/L U/L umol/L  umol/L
                  2020-02-11    2020-02-12     NaN  NaN     94.0  2.0   U/L U/L umol/L  umol/L
   2    102       2020-02-12    2020-02-13     25.0 22.0    NaN  NaN    U/L U/L umol/L  umol/L
                  2020-02-13    2020-02-14     NaN  NaN     98.0 3.0    U/L U/L umol/L  umol/L
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt using `groupby()` and `apply()`

- Step 1 transforms the grouped data into data frames
- Step 2 re index

---

```
#Step 1
def pivot(x):
  output = {}
  for index, row in x.iterrows():
    output[ row['TestCode'] ]  = row['TestResult']
    output[ row['TestCode'] + '_Units']  = row['Units']
  return pd.Series(output).to_frame().transpose()

gp = df.groupby(['CaseNo', 'PatientID', 'CollectionDate', 'RequestDate'])    
df_tmp1 = gp.apply(pivot)

#Step2
df_final = df_tmp1.droplevel(4).reset_index()
```

---

Edit: `pivot()` can be turned into a comprehension lambda, if you want to fit everything into a one-liner

```
def pivot(gp_df):
    return pd.Series(dict(
      ( pair for index, row in gp_df.iterrows() for pair in
        [ ( row['TestCode'] ,  row['TestResult'] ) , 
          ( row['TestCode'] + '_Units' ,  row['Units'] ) ] )
    )).to_frame().transpose()
```